# Compilation error: "-Xcoroutines has no effect: coroutines are enabled anyway in 1.3 and beyond"

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin, compiler-errors, kotlinx.coroutines

When I try to compile my Android app written in Kotlin, I get the following compilation error, and my build fails:

```
w: -Xcoroutines has no effect: coroutines are enabled anyway in 1.3 and beyond
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turns out it is actually very easy to solve this problem, and I thought I'd document my solution for people who will undoubtedly stumble upon the same problem in the future.

Simply remove the following block from your app-level build.gradle, hit "Sync Now" in Android Studio and rebuild:

```
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, bingo. I've lost an hour finding where did i forget to remove something experimental.

Comment: I also had to remove `kotlin.coroutines=enable` from gradle.properties in addition to get rid of the warning

Answer (score 7):

You don't need this anymore when using Kotlin 1.3 as it removed the "experimental" nature of Coroutines. See [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/10/kotlin-1-3/):

> **Coroutines are now stable**
>
> Coroutines are a modern way to write non-blocking asynchronous code that’s easy to understand and evolve. It’s a powerful tool for anything from offloading work onto background workers to implementing complicated network protocols. The *kotlinx.coroutines library hits 1.0* release and provides a solid foundation for managing asynchronous jobs at any scale including composition, cancelation, exception handling and UI-specific use cases.

You probably have a missing reference in your build script, e.g.:

```
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```